# Simulate virtual camera which preserves color information

Tags: vtk, point-cloud-library

I have a virtual scanner that generates a 2.5-D view of a point cloud (i.e. a 2D-projection of a 3D point cloud) depending on camera position. I'm using the `vtkCamera.GetProjectionTransformMatrix()` to get transformation matrix from world/global to camera coordinates.

However, if the input point cloud has color information for points I would like to preserve it.

Here are the relevant lines:

```cpp
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> vis; // camera location, viewpoint and up direction for vis were already defined before
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRendererCollection> rens = vis->getRendererCollection();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> win = vis->getRenderWindow();

win->SetSize(xres, yres); // xres and yres are predefined resolutions
win->Render();

float dwidth = 2.0f / float(xres),
    dheight = 2.0f / float(yres);

float *depth = new float[xres * yres];
win->GetZbufferData(0, 0, xres - 1, yres - 1, &(depth[0]));

vtkRenderer *ren = rens->GetFirstRenderer();
vtkCamera *camera = ren->GetActiveCamera();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> projection_transform = camera->GetProjectionTransformMatrix(ren->GetTiledAspectRatio(), 0, 1);

Eigen::Matrix4f mat1;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        mat1(i, j) = static_cast<float> (projection_transform->Element[i][j]);

mat1 = mat1.inverse().eval();
```

Now, mat1 is used to transform coordinates to camera-view:

```cpp
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr &cloud;

int ptr = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < yres; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < xres; ++x, ++ptr)
    {
        pcl::PointXYZ &pt = (*cloud)[ptr];

        if (depth[ptr] == 1.0)
        {
            pt.x = pt.y = pt.z = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
            continue;
        }

        Eigen::Vector4f world_coords(dwidth  * float(x) - 1.0f,
            dheight * float(y) - 1.0f,
            depth[ptr],
            1.0f);
        world_coords = mat1 * world_coords;

        float w3 = 1.0f / world_coords[3];
        world_coords[0] *= w3;
        world_coords[1] *= w3;
        world_coords[2] *= w3;

        pt.x = static_cast<float> (world_coords[0]);
        pt.y = static_cast<float> (world_coords[1]);
        pt.z = static_cast<float> (world_coords[2]);
    }
}
```

I want the virtual scanner to return `pcl::PointXYZRGB` point cloud with color information.

Any help on how to implement this from someone experienced in VTK would save some of my time.

**It's possible that I missed a relevant question already asked here - in that case, please point me to it.** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you want to get the color in which the point was rendered into the `win` RenderWindow, you should be able to get the data from the rendering buffer by calling

`float* pixels = win->GetRGBAPixelData(0, 0, xres - 1, yres - 1, 0/1)`.

This should give you each pixel of the rendering buffer as an array in the format `[R0, G0, B0, A0, R1, G1, B1, A1, R2....]`. The last parameter which I wrote as `0/1` is whether the data should be taken from front or back opengl buffers. I presume by default double buffering should be on, so then you want to read from back buffer (use '1'), but I am not sure.

Once you have that, you can get the color in your second loop for all pixels that belong to points (`depth[ptr] != 1.0`) as:

```
pt.R = pixels[4*ptr];
pt.G = pixels[4*ptr + 1];
pt.B = pixels[4*ptr + 2];
```

You should call `win->ReleaseRGBAPixelData(pixels)` once you're done with it.

Comment: That's what I wanted, yes! I have set the last parameter (front) to 1, works fine. When exporting values to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>`, they should (probably) be multiplied by 255. Thanks!